# prevArrow messing up the image width

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, slick.js

I have implemented Slick.js to mine project but for some reason when I use nextArrow and prevArrow my picture gets cropped to around 60% of the width, I have tried to make a custom class which deffiness a width of 100% but that didn't solve the problem. Just checked only prevArrow causes a problem

Here is how it should look like:
[image: Expected]

Here is how it looks like:
[image: Reality]

```js
$('.slider-one').not(".slick-initialized").slick({
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 3000,
  dots: true,
  prevArrow: ".site-slider .slider-btn .prev",
  nextArrow: ".site-slider .slider-btn .next"
});
```

```css
.wid {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 500px;
}


/*Slider*/

.site-sider {
  position: relative;
}

.position-top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
}

.site-slider .slider-btn .prev,
.site-slider .slider-btn .next {
  background-color: #091a5d;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.site-slider:hover .slider-btn .prev,
.site-slider:hover .slider-btn .next {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.right-0 {
  right: 0;
}

.slick-dots {
  left:50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 16px 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 50%;
}

.slick-dots li {
  margin: 0 0.6rem;
}

.slick-dots button {
  display: block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  text-indent: -99999px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.slick-dots .slick-active button {
  transform: scale(2.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.205);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!--Font-->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/158e82d513.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--Slider-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />

  <!--Styles-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <main>

    <!--Slider-->
    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
      <div class="site-slider">
        <div class="slider-one">
          <div>
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" class="wid img-fluid" alt="Slika 1">
          </div>
          <div>
            <img src="https://www.talkwalker.com/images/2020/blog-headers/image-analysis.png" class="wid img-fluid" alt="Slika 2">
          </div>
          <div>
            <img src="https://p.bigstockphoto.com/GeFvQkBbSLaMdpKXF1Zv_bigstock-Aerial-View-Of-Blue-Lakes-And--227291596.jpg" class="wid img-fluid" alt="Slika 3">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-btn">
          <span class="prev position-top"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></span>
          <span class="next position-top right-0"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

So if anyone knows how to solve this, help a brother out :) <3

Comment: Can you create a snippet in which we can run your slider?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier posted it

Comment: I meant a code snippet, the images tell the same story as you already explained. We need to be able to inspect the HTML and CSS while running your slider. Look for the `<>` icon in the question editor to create a snippet. There include your HTML, CSS, JS, jQuery and Slick.js to create an interactive example.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I dont know how to insert images into it, but u get the rough idea

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I have added pictures into it

Comment: Seems to work fine? Can you check again if the problem is present in your snippet?

Comment: Thats what I'm suprised, it snippet it works fine but it doesent work in my project

Answer (score 0):

Instead of class use image directly

```
$('.slider-one').not(".slick-initialized").slick({
  prevArrow:"<img class='a-left control-c prev slick-prev' src='../images/shoe_story/arrow-left.png'>",
  nextArrow:"<img class='a-right control-c next slick-next' src='../images/shoe_story/arrow-right.png'>"  });
```

Comment: use icons instead of images replace <img> with <i>

Comment: you cant do that, its js due to " " clashing

Answer (score 0):

If Your are using bootstrap 3 Use this

```
.slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before {
            font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings","slick", sans-serif;
            font-size: 40px;
    }
    .slick-prev:before { content: "\e257"; }
    .slick-next:before { content: "\e258"; }
```

Comment: font font awesome